# React not giving error for Navbar using react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

thanks for looking at my problem, long story short I'm new to react and trying to implement a NavBar into my application. React isnt throwing an error in console localhost just renders a whitepage). When I remove my  Component, everything renders out fine except the nav of course. Any help is thanked.

Menu.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Component } from 'react';

class Menu extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
        <>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
               <Container>
                   <Nav className="me-auto">
                       <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                       <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
                       <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
                   </Nav>
               </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </>
       );
    } 
}

export default Menu;
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import Header from './components/layout/header';
import Menu from './components/layout/Menu';
import Footer from './components/layout/footer';



class App extends Component{
  render(){
  return (
        <div className="App">
        <Header/>
        <Menu/>
        <Footer/>
        </div>
  );
  }
}
```

export default App;

Comment: your code should function normally, there might be something you missed or mistyped check again or try to replicate the problem somewhere else, here's a sample with your component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-phoebe-75wqni

Comment: Yea, im not sure what the problem is

Comment: Have your tried removing node modules and running "npm i" ?

Answer (score 0):

I see you used lowercase name for the component files, is the first letter of the menu component file actually uppercase?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback....yes it is uppercase